# Как исправить интерфейс 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс

[image: Меню инфоблока]

Использую локалку Open Server, на хостингах всё нормально.
По всей видимости дело в стилях, но что нужно с ними сделать, чтобы исправить это

В консоли выводит:

```
Refused to apply style from '<URL>' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
iblock_list_admin.php:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://baza.market/bitrix/themes/.default/compatible.css?16467554682827' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
iblock_list_admin.php:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://baza.market/bitrix/themes/.default/modules.css?1646756118241798' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
iblock_list_admin.php:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://baza.market/bitrix/components/bitrix/iblock.element.selector/templates/.default/style.css?16467548435325' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
iblock_list_admin.php:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://baza.market/bitrix/components/bitrix/main.ui.filter/templates/.default/style.css?164675491352200' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
iblock_list_admin.php:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://baza.market/bitrix/components/bitrix/main.ui.grid/templates/.default/style.css?164675483378606' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в модуле apache+nginx.
Я переставил на чистый apache и удалил из конфигурационного файла следующие строки:

```
    <LocationMatch "/\.(?!well-known)">
    Require             all denied
    </LocationMatch>
```